# Iterating over matrices and create Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

By using the following script I am able to get the dictionary of the connection type for each matrix type. I want to get the values updated when new matrix with similar header comes, if the header is different then add that different header in the dictionary. I am unable to get the update in values when the second matrix come:

for the following matrix:

```
   0.0   2.0  1.0  1.0
   2.0   0.0  1.0  1.0
   1.0   1.0  0.0  1.0
   1.0   1.0  1.0  0.0
```

with the list l as matrix title

```
l = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
```

it becomes

```
      A    A     B     B
A   0.0   2.0  1.0  1.0
A   2.0   0.0  1.0  1.0
B   1.0   1.0  0.0  1.0
B   1.0   1.0  1.0  0.0
```

**Script**

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for ix, iy in np.ndindex(matrix.shape):
        i = 1
        if int(matrix[ix][iy]) != 0:
            elem = l[ix]
            connection_index = matrix[ix][iy]
            connection_key = l[iy]
            if elm not in d[elm].keys(): 
                if connection_index ==1:
                    d[elm][connection_key +"_corner"] = i 
                elif connection_index ==2:
                     d[elm][connection_key +"_edge"] = i 
                elif connection_index >=3:
                     d[elm][connection_key +"_face"] = i
print(d)
```

gives:

```
defaultdict(dict,
            {'A': {'A_edge': 1, 'B_corner': 1},
             'B': {'A_corner': 1, 'B_corner': 1}})
```

now when the second matrix comes say same as before then it should be

```
defaultdict(dict,
                {'A': {'A_edge': 2, 'B_corner': 2},
                 'B': {'A_corner': 2, 'B_corner': 2}})
```

but I am still getting

```
defaultdict(dict,
                {'A': {'A_edge': 1, 'B_corner': 1},
                 'B': {'A_corner': 1, 'B_corner': 1}})
```

One thing I know is because I need to update 'i', and tried outside the loop, but did not work.

Here, we say edge when the matrix element is 2, corner when it is 1. For Example (A, A) has 2 in the first row so we say

```
{'A': {'A_edge': 1}}
```

could anyone please help on getting this updated result?

Thanks in advance.